# How to enforce resource level permissions with OData

Tags: c#, odata

I've been reading through documentation on OData, but I haven't been able to find anything about resource level access control.

In an OData example, the person russellwhyte is fetching trip 1003.  But how can I verify that the requester has access to both People = 'russellwhyte' and Trip = 1003?  What if the requester had access to 'rusellwhyte', but changed trip 1003, to 1004 which belongs to another person, and therefore the request should be rejected because 1004 belongs to another person, and because the requester doesn't have access to trip 1004.

```
GET
serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(1003)
```

The request above could be rejected for three reasons,

1. The requester doesn't have permission to access russelwhyte's data.
2. The requester doesn't have permission to access trip 1003.
3. The requester changes the trip Id to an invalid one, 1004.  (1004 belong to another person)

If this was a simple route definition (`[Route("people/{personId}/trips/{tripId}")]`) I could grab both Ids from the request then perform the necessary permission checks, but I haven't found its equivalent for OData.

Comment: https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

When `trips` is evaluated, it should already have the filter of `personId`, for instance if the `tripId` was not specified then the query that is executed should be something similar to this Linq to Entities expression

```
from p in db.People
where p.Id == personId
select p.Trips
```

So when `tripId` is present, the only difference should be that the response applies a further filter over the top of the previous query.

This way, when the wrong `tripId` or `personId` is provided, the result would be either an empty object or **Http 404**, *Not Found*. (depending on your implementation)

You have not mentioned what middleware, OData version or ORM you are using so it's all speculation, on OData v4 using the ASP.Net ODataLib, I had to implement my own logic on each controller that I wanted to support this type of nested navigation but the convention was the same, each navigation route level added a new criteria to the select query over the top of the query provided by the parent route's controller.